# Sending messages to Kafka from Event Hub

Tags: azure, apache-kafka, azure-eventhub

We have a situation where we need to send messages that have landed in an Azure Event Hub to a topic in an external Kafka topic. No transformation, just read the event from AEH and forward to Kafka. From a volume perspective, we'll likely have between 1-3 million messages a day, so the service should be running all the time. My question is what's the best Azure compute service to do something so basic but running all the time?

For Context: we currently use Azure Functions to do a myriad of things in the ecosystem but they're either triggered or timed and short lived. We use Service Fabric in other places as well. Thinking that Durable Functions could be interesting here as well. Perhaps even a low code, no code way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest enabling Kafka compatibility mode in eventhub, then using regular Kafka tooling such as MirrorMaker2 for this

Comment: That's interesting. We're sending change data capture (CDC) messages from SQL server to AEH via Qlik Replicate and we're only licensed for SQL to AEH. I would have to check to see if Qlik can send to a Kafka enabled AEH.

Comment: I don't have experience with Qlik, but I imagine it should have a regular Kafka client connector

Comment: They do but we're not licensed for it and won't be acquiring the license anytime soon.